# Why don't I get the same decimal value by converting a hexadecimal value in PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, type-conversion, hex, decimal

I'm trying to convert a hexadecimal value to a decimal value in PHP.

In PHP, my code is as follows:

```
<?
ini_set("precision", 50);
echo hexdec("98999977485558");
?>
```

I get the following result: 42953080870294872

When I went to check the result of the hexadecimal to decimal conversion on some sites, I was surprised to see that 98999977485558 became 42953080870294870.

I tested with this site for example: https://codebeautify.org/hex-decimal-converter

After looking at the source code, I see that it uses the parseInt function of JavaScript.

So I do a test with the following code:

```
parseInt("98999977485558", 16);
```

With this code, I get the result: 42953080870294870.

So I'm looking for the correct decimal value for the hexadecimal value 98999977485558.

Is it 42953080870294872 or 42953080870294870?

Also, why does the result look different between PHP and JavaScript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: So, PHP returns the correct result?

Comment: Yes, the value is too big to be shown correctly in JS.

Comment: See @Umberto Salsi's answer on [this thread](https://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/759136-changing-precision-level-floating-point-variables)